# Go cannot read last nvarchar(max) value from MS SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, go

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ... ,
    grade as [grade],
    grade as [grade2]
    FROM dbo.[qc_runs] r

    JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

I send it to MS SQL Server 2014 from my Go code and want to get back data (I am using `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` driver). However, I can read first `grade` value (type `nvarchar(max)`), but second one arrives empty! These are the same table fields, just duplicated. **If I delete first grade value from query and leave just one, it will still arrive empty!** The column is described as following:

```
[grade] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
```

SQL Management Studio executes this query just fine, both `grade` values are not empty, but Go code doesn't!

UPDATE #1
Go code:

```
evaluations, err := db.Query("EXEC qa.dbo.sp_get_evaluation_list ?", uid)
if err != nil {
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return list, nil
    }
    return list, err
}

// Get column names
colNames, err := evaluations.Columns()
if err != nil {
    log.Logf("Failed to get columns: %v", err)
    return list, err
}

// Result is your slice string.
readCols := make([]interface{}, len(colNames))

// Read data
for evaluations.Next() {

    writeCols := make([]string, len(colNames))
    for i := range writeCols {
        readCols[i] = &writeCols[i]
    }

    evaluations.Scan(readCols...)

    for i := range writeCols {
        fmt.Println(colNames[i], ": ", writeCols[i])
    }
    ...
}
```

Output:

```
...
grade :  <some text from DB>
grade2 :
```

Comment: Add the Golang code where you are handling the queries result returning from database.

Comment: @Himanshu, updated post

Comment: You need to provide the sproc code as well.

Comment: @iamnp Can you post the output of `fmt.Println(evaluations)` which will show the returned data.

Comment: @Himanshu, `fmt.Println(evaluations)` prints raw data: `&{0xc042336000 0x889bb0 0xc0423061e0 0x53f460 0xc042036440 {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []}`

Comment: @iamnp convert it into string. so that we can read

Comment: @Himanshu, it doesn't work like that :(

Comment: @iamnp donnot skip the errors print them and check them. Because there is no problem seems inside the golang code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, `evaluations.Scan(readCols...)` returned error `err sql: Scan error on column index 3: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *string`, and left the rest of array blank

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a go programmer. But you need to name those fields differently. How could your code possible discern between the first and second `[grade]`?

```
SELECT ... ,
    grade as [grade],
    grade as [grade2]
    FROM dbo.[qc_runs] r

    JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

Given that you're getting an empty value on the second read, I suspect that the go driver (and the data reader you're using from it) is **one-way** only.

Comment: Renaming one value didn't help. First read if the value is the last one also fails - see original question